# Spark Error: Executor XXX finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I build the standalone spark cluster on Oracle linux. I add this line in **spark-env.sh** on Master:

```
 export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=x.x.x.x
```

And add these lines in **spark-env.sh** in both Master and Worker:

```
 export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.8
 export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.8
```

Also, I insert IP of worker in **worker** file for both Master and Worker. I start Spark Cluster in this way:
In master:

```
 /opt/spark/sbin/start-master.sh
```

In worker:

```
 /opt/spark/sbin/start-worker.sh spark://x.x.x.x:7077
```

In fact, I have one worker and one master. I configure **~/.bashrc** like this:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/opt/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_25
 export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
 alias python=/usr/bin/python3.8
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 export PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4:$PATH
 export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
 export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
 export PYSPARK_HOME=/usr/bin/python3.8
 export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3.8
 export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.8
```

While I run **spark-submit** I have no error, but the command run for ever without any result. I see these line:

```
 22/03/04 12:07:40 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks resource profile 0
 22/03/04 12:07:41 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20220304120738-0000/0 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
 22/03/04 12:07:41 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20220304120738-0000/0 removed: Command exited with code 1
 22/03/04 12:07:41 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20220304120738-0000/3 on worker-20220304120443-192.9.200.68-42185 (192.9.200.68:42185) with 2 core(s)
 22/03/04 12:07:41 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20220304120738-0000/3 on hostPort 192.9.200.68:42185 with 2 core(s), 2.0 GiB RAM
```

I check worker log, and I have this error:

```
 22/03/04 12:07:38 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with m$
 22/03/04 12:07:38 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/opt/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark/conf/:/opt/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx2048M" "-Dspark.driver.port=40345" "-XX:+PrintGC$
 22/03/04 12:07:38 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/opt/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark/conf/:/opt/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx2048M" "-Dspark.driver.port=40345" "-XX:+PrintGC$
 22/03/04 12:07:38 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/opt/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark/conf/:/opt/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx2048M" "-Dspark.driver.port=40345" "-XX:+PrintGC$
 22/03/04 12:07:41 INFO Worker: Executor app-20220304120738-0000/0 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
 22/03/04 12:07:41 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle and non-RDD files associated with the finished executor 0
 22/03/04 12:07:41 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Executor is not registered (appId=app-20220304120738-0000, execId=0)
```

**spark-submit** is like this:

```
 /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master spark://x.x.x.x:7077 --files etl/sparkConfig.json --py-files etl/brn_utils.py,etl/cst.py,etl/cst_utils.py,etl/emp_utils.py,etl/general_utils.py,etl/grouping.py,etl/grp_state.py,etl/conn.py etl/main.py
```

I test in **root** user, also I create **spark** user and nothing change.

Would you please guide me what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

I think it was because of network problem. Since when I added this part to **spark-submit** every thing worked fine.

```
 --conf spark.driver.host=x.x.x.x
```

In fact, I run this:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master spark://x.x.x.x:7077 --conf spark.driver.host=x.x.x.x --files etl/sparkConfig.json --py-files etl/brn_utils.py,etl/cst.py,etl/cst_utils.py,etl/emp_utils.py,etl/general_utils.py,etl/grouping.py,etl/grp_state.py,etl/conn.py etl/main.py
```

Be careful to copy your program in all of node at the same place.
Also,because I accessed to the cluster remotely, I use **SSH tunnel** to have UI in my computer. Like this:

```
 ssh spark@master_ip -N -L 4040:master_ip:8080
```

In above command *4040* is port of my computer and *8080* is port of master. After creating **SSH Tunnel** I could open spark UI with writing **Master_IP:8080** in my browser.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: This also worked for me. It looks like adding `--conf spark.driver.host=x.x.x.x` fixes the problem.